# render xml на основе xslt в react

Tags: xml, reactjs, xslt

есть проект на React. С сервера приходит json, в котором передается

{"xml": "XML содержимого",
"xsml": "XSLT содержимое"}

нужно в реакте отрендерить таблицу xml на основе схемы xslt

Comment: на чем написан бэкенд?

Comment: сервер на java, для разработки сейчас заглушка на nodejs
отсылается сейчас в виде строки